# measure and possibly speed up VS Code extension installation in Docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with DevContainer extension to run inside a Docker container.
It works great, but every time either VS Code is updated or the Dockerfile and I have to rebuild the container it takes few minutes to install the extensions I need inside the container.

```
[218513 ms] Start: Run in container: cd /root/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f; export VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/root/.vscode-server; /root/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/server.sh --disable-telemetry --extensions-download-dir /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache --install-extension ms-python.python --install-extension ms-python.vscode-pylance --force
[537378 ms] Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'ms-python.python' v2020.12.424452561...
Installing extension 'ms-python.vscode-pylance' v2020.12.2...
Extension 'ms-python.vscode-pylance' v2020.12.2 was successfully installed.
Extension 'ms-python.python' v2020.12.424452561 was successfully installed.
[537379 ms] 
[537379 ms] Start: Run in container: ls /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache || true
[537387 ms] ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561
ms-python.vscode-pylance-2020.12.2
ms-toolsai.jupyter-2020.12.414227025
```

I have 2 questions about this:

1. Is it possible to measure what is taking the time? is it download or install (or both) that takes that long?
2. If it is download that takes most of the time, is there a way to cache the extensions?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solution to speed up container initialization:

One way is to use *docker volumes* and mount that under `$HOME/.vscode-server`. In that case VS Code will use the instance already installed.

The other way is to *mount a local folder* into the dev-container as `$HOME` folder. It may slow down the overall performance of the container but we will also maintain permanent session eg. bash history, azure session, etc.

The second solution has currently some issue around extension installation (see: [issue related to .installExtensionsMarker file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5229)) so for the moment I would recommend using docker volumes.

For more detail on how to configure the volumes see the following section of the `Advanced Container Configuration` document:

- [Avoiding extension reinstalls on container rebuild](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_avoiding-extension-reinstalls-on-container-rebuild)

I would also recommend to use some final image that is already have been built and which is pushed to container registry to avoid installation of any python or other packages during `container rebuild`.